# Cannot Connect Java to MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql

I have database connection problem from java to mysql via LAN. I had insterted mysql connector java to the IDE Library, and ping to DBServer is success. I have change localhost to become ip address of DBServer (192.168.1.9:3306), but it is cannot connect from Java to DBServer. Why cannot connect to mysql and How to solve this problem?? I have the source code like this :

```
public static void Inisialisasi (){

try {

       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

            dbconn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.9:3306/vestryl?" +
                                                 "user=root&password=root");
            dbconn.setAutoCommit(false);
            //dbconn.setReadOnly(false);
            Statement stmt = dbconn.createStatement();
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new  SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

            System.out.println("Terkoneksi ke Database pada " + sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
}

catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Koneksi ke DB error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: Can you add your code, how are you connecting to the server? maybe try and create a simple application that just connects and outputs some string if the connection is successful or an error if not. Maybe the error can tell you why.

Comment: Is MySQL listening on that IP? Out of the box it listens only on 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Do the following to ensure that ensure that your issue is not due to any network or MySQL configuration related issues.

1. Bind address in your my.cnf/my.ini file should be un-commented and configured 
   as 192.168.1.9 *(Assuming "192.168.1.9" is the IP address of your MySQL Server)*
2. After doing above, restart the MySQL Server
3. Try a telnet from the server where your Java Application is installed using 
   command `telnet 192.168.1.9 3306`
4. If telnet is happening, then your MySQL configuraion & Network connectivity 
   is fine.

After this, you need to check if your mysql user and password is working fine. For that your can do the below steps.

1. Install MySQL Client in the server where your Java application is deployed
2. Then use the below command to access MySQL server from MySQL Client in your 
    Application Server `mysql -uroot -p -h192.168.1.9`
3. When it prompts for the password, provide the same
4. If you are able to login, then your network and user configuration is fine 
   with MySQL. You can then focus on your application part

In case any of the above steps fail, do reply so that I can be of help. In that case, you may please include a screenshot of what went wrong as well.

Answer (score 0):

My Source Code like this:

public static void getConnection (){

```
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        dbconn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.9:3306/vestryl?" +
                                             "user=root&password=root");
        dbconn.setAutoCommit(false);
        //dbconn.setReadOnly(false);
        Statement stmt = dbconn.createStatement();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new  SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

        System.out.println("Connect to DB on " + sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Koneksi ke DB error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```